# Running multiple instances of a program through shell with plist works fine until I use an ampersand

Tags: shell, plist, render, after-effects

I'm trying to run multiple instances of After Effects (aerender) core on Mac which can be done with shell.

To my understanding that basically drills down to looping the following.

```
/bin/tcsh -c "/Applications/Adobe\ After\ Effects\ CC\ 2014/aerender \
-project $fileToRender -comp $compToRender \
-RStemplate \"Multi-Machine Settings\" \
-OMtemplate \"Multi-Machine Sequence JPEG\" \
-output $outputLocation/\[\#\#\#\#\].jpg -continueOnMissingFootage" &
```

I've written a script that works perfectly fine when run manually. The render engines start and that's all good the render engines start running and by looking at my activity monitor I can see they're rendering (CPU usage ±200%)

Problem comes in when I run my script using plist. Everything seems to go fine, the render engines are started however they startup and then go into idle mode (CPU usage ±1%). If they get wrong input they'd quit, but now they just go in idle mode or something..

Strange thing is that when I drop the ampersand `&` the render engine instance works perfectly fine with `plist`. However, without the `&` I can only run one instance and that doesn't make much of a render engine.

My guess is that it has to do with permissions. I'm clueless however how to fix it. I tried using `nohup dev/null` but that didn't fix it for me.

I also tried changing the permissions of programs directly involved but that also didn't resolve it.

Hope you guys can help :)

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong, it seems like it should work. If you are redirecting std-err to `/dev/null` someplace in your project, remove that so you can see error messages that maybe generated. OR does the Adobe program have a cmd-line option to generate log files? Good luck!